# ArcGIS Mosaic Layer and Geoprocessing Services

Tags: geoprocessing-service, arcgis-enterprise

When I publish this script tool where I want to make a Mosaic Layer from a mosaic dataset inside a geodatabase on a shared and registered folder:

```
arcpy.management.MakeMosaicLayer(r"\\machineName\\Subfolder\\path\\gdbNamed.gdb\\mosaicDatasetName", "bestand_lyr")
```

the input path gets substituted with `g_ESRI_variable_1 = '\\\\machineName\\Subfolder\\path\\gdbNamed.gdb\\mosaicDatasetName'`   
causing `ERROR 999999: Something unexpected caused the tool to fail. Contact Esri Technical Support (http://esriurl.com/support) to Report a Bug, and refer to the error help for potential solutions or workarounds. Image Server is not supported with the current license.` when running the tool. How could I prevent this?
Substituting the automatically generated variable in the published script with various backslash variants did not help.

Does it maybe have to do with the character of the file directory?
In the Windows Explorer, this is how the directory looks, these are not normal folders, I guess?

[image]

I have also tried to input the mosaic layer in the functions needed (SelectLayerByLocation)  directly as a parameter of type Mosaic Layer and setting up a variable with name matching
`mosaicLayer_var = "NameOfMosaicLayerInContentPane"` (did not work).